# spring.jackson.serialization.fail-on-empty-beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson, deserialization

I'm trying to understand when the fail on empty bean happens , from doc :

> public static final SerializationFeature FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS
>   Feature that determines what happens when no accessors are found for a type (and there are no annotations to indicate it is meant to be serialized). If enabled (default), an exception is thrown to indicate these as non-serializable types; if disabled, they are serialized as empty Objects, i.e. without any properties.
>   Note that empty types that this feature has only effect on those "empty" beans that do not have any recognized annotations (like @JsonSerialize): ones that do have annotations do not result in an exception being thrown.
>
> Feature is enabled by default.

Now I have tried to create an empty POJO (no getters ):

```
@Component
public class Wrapper2 {

    private String name;

}
```

The wrapper class which I want to serialize :

```
@Component
public class Wrapper {

        @Autowired
        private Wrapper2 wrapper2;


}
```

The controller:

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @Autowired
    private Wrapper wrapper;

        @GetMapping("/test")
        public Wrapper test() {
          return wrapper;
        }
    }
```

however I always get the wrapper serialized  even with adding/removing getter and setter for wrapper2. can anyone explain when the error can happen ?

Comment: Where's the empty bean?

Comment: @user7294900 according to the doc any that hasn't accessors "happens when no accessors are found for a type" I don't have getters for both `wrapper` and `wrapper2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need your bean to be **empty** and **without recognized annotations**

> Note that empty types that this feature has only effect on those "empty" beans that do not have any recognized annotations

So if you remove the annotations it'll failed

```
public class Wrapper {

}
```

Error will be as

```
Unrecognized field "wrapper" (class com.Wrapper ), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
```

[Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/blob/4a7fb129f73173e18280f77c350c6fdc1f101428/src/main/java/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/SerializerProvider.java) relevant code applied when mark it as `UnknownSerializer`:

> ```
> if (isEnabled(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS)) {
>         if (ser instanceof UnknownSerializer) {
>             return true;
> ```

Similar exception with nested empty class:

```
public class Wrapper {
   private Wrapper2 wrapper2;
}
```